# For loop - Sorting each character alphabetically within a list of words

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a list of words that I would like to sort by character in a list:

```
['alumni', 'orphan', 'binge', 'peanut', 'necktie']
```

I wanted to sort these alphabetically so they would end up being a list of:

```
['ailmnu', 'ahnopr', 'begin', 'aenptu', 'ceeiknt']
```

So far my code has been embarrassing:

```
for i in range(len(splitfoo)):
    splitedfootmp = sorted(splitfoo[i])
```

which splits the words into characters like this: `['a', 'i', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'u']`
but i cannot figure out how to turn it back into `['ailmnu']`

Is there even a way to do this without going through all the trouble?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do your whole thing nicely:

```
items = ['alumni', 'orphan', 'binge', 'peanut', 'necktie']
sorted_items = ["".join(sorted(item)) for item in items]
```

Here I am using a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), which is a nice way of making small snippets like this. You can, if you want, expand it out to:

```
items = ['alumni', 'orphan', 'binge', 'peanut', 'necktie']
sorted_items = []
for item in items:
    sorted_items.append("".join(sorted(item)))
```

But clearly, the list comprehension is a nicer (and faster than the above or using `map()`) solution in this case.

It's also worth noting it's not very pythonic to use a for loop like that. Compare:

```
for i in range(len(splitfoo)):
    splitedfootmp = sorted(splitfoo[i])

for item in splitfoo:
    splitedfootmp = sorted(item)
```

They both do the same thing, but the latter is more clear and pythonic.

Answer (score 4):

```
In [1]: ''.join(['a', 'i', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'u'])
Out[1]: 'ailmnu'
```

Here is a complete program:

```
In [2]: l = ['alumni', 'orphan', 'binge', 'peanut', 'necktie']

In [3]: map(lambda w: ''.join(sorted(w)), l)
Out[3]: ['ailmnu', 'ahnopr', 'begin', 'aenptu', 'ceeiknt']
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at `string.join()`.

You might also be able to simplify your code using the `map()` function.